# Howto use trimSpaces in Glassfish

Tags: java, glassfish, glassfish-4.1

I need remove indent of my output html to reduce html size so I want use "trimSpace", but Glassfish ignore the option.

I added this code to glassfish-web.xml

```html
<jsp-config>
        <property name="development" value="false" />
        <property name="genStrAsCharArray" value="true" />
        <property name="keepgenerated" value="true" />
        <property name="compilerSourceVM" value="1.7" />
        <property name="compilerTargetVM" value="1.7" />
        <property name="reload-interval" value="-1" />
        <property name="mappedfile" value="false" />
        <property name="trimSpaces" value="true" />
        <property name="suppressSmap" value="true" />
        <property name="classdebuginfo" value="false" />
  </jsp-config>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Since you posted a question tagged with JSF, are you using JSP servlets here or JSF?

Comment: I use JSF but I try with JSP serverlets, I did not find anything for JSF